# Steps to configure Soap webservice in Hybris.?

Tags: web-services, soap, sap-commerce-cloud

Can someone help with the steps for configuring SOAP web service in Hybris.
We have received a requirement wherein the business user wants to consume a SOAP web service. They do not support REST web service.

Answer (score 2):

Hybris does not provide integration with SOAP based web services. We did a similar kind of integration with SOAP webservice in Hybris using XJC. To configure SOAP web service, you will need to do the following:

1. Create a custom extension and define the following dependencies in your external-dependencies.xml to download the following JAR'sin your custom extension library :

- jaxb-api
- jaxb-xjc
- jaxws-api
- jaxws-tools

2. Define an XJC task in the buildcallback.xml of your custom extension to generate the java classes out of your WSDL.

```
<xjc schema="${CustomPathToWsdl}/custom.wsdl" destdir="${customExtensionBaseDir}/gensrc/" extension="true" package="com.mycustomextension.ws.dto" removeOldOutput="no">
  <arg value="-wsdl" />
  <produces dir="${CustomFolder}/custom" includes="**/*" />
</xjc>
```

3. Once the java classes are generated, you can use the *ObjectFactory* class to create a request DTO and then setting the request attributes using setters.

4. Configure the WebServiceTemplate in your custom extension spring.xml.

```
<bean id="clientMessageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory" />

    <bean id="customJaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="contextPath" value="***package.name.of.generated.dtos***" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="customWsMessageSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender">
        <property name="credentials">
            <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials">
                <constructor-arg value="${custom.username}" />
                <constructor-arg value="${custom.password}" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="connectionTimeout" value="30" />
        <property name="readTimeout" value="30" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="customWebServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientMessageFactory" />
        <property name="defaultUri" value="**custom webservice URI**" />
        <property name="marshaller" ref="customJaxbMarshaller" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="customJaxbMarshaller" />
        <property name="messageSender" ref="customWsMessageSender" />

    </bean>
```

5. Create a custom integration service class and inject the *WebServiceTemplate*  .Call any of the template methods to marshal,send and receive the response.

```
 wrappedResponse = (JAXBElement<CustomRequestDTO>) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(defaultCustSearchURI, wrappedResponse);
```

Hope this helps!